# Validate presence/validity of a key/value in Ruby Openstruct

Tags: ruby, validation, openstruct

Is there a standard way to validate key/values (presence of a key, whether it's a valid value) in Ruby's Openstruct? In a pure Ruby, no Rails/Sinatra, but in a similar way to validations in ActiveRecord or  ActiveModel::Validations is doing.
For example, to check that Openstruct contains "id" key, check that a "name" key's value is not longer than X characters, check that "protocol" key's value contains only specific values such as "tcp", but not "abc",  etc.

Comment: Look like you want to add behaviour to your "Struct" - maybe you just need to make it a class ? Strucs are made for simple structure without much behaviour...

Comment: The openstruct is created from json received from another server, or constructed directly by the user. There is a lot of dynamic content that should not (and could not) be validated at this point, but there is a certain number of attributes (3-5) that I'd like to validate for their presence and their content. Hence my question is regarding key/value validation - whether anything standard exists in relation to OpenStruct.